# Replacing bulbs in Harbor Breeze ceilng fan with remote

Tags: electrical, ceiling, light

I'd like to use the brighter better energy LED bulbs but when I put them in - they blinked continuously. I think this MAY be because the fan is on a remote control.This blinking seemed dangerous so I removed the bulbs. I desperately want MORE light from that fixture. The limit is 40W. Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried leaving one bulb incandescent?  That may do it.

Comment: Does the fan remote also dim the lights?  Are you OK with getting a different fan remote?

Answer (score 1):

Double check that the bulbs are dimmable.

I have a Harbor Breeze remote control fan with Phillips dimmable LED bulbs and it works well.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.